# fetch mobile number from android inserted sim programatically

Tags: android, development-environment

There is a proper way to fetch a number from inserted SIM of Android device? I tried using TelephoneManager,SubscriptionManager and HintRequest, not giving desired result.

Comment: Are you looking for the phone number associated with the sim card?

Comment: yes,i want to fetch automatically  my both sim card number which are inserted in my device

Answer (score 0):

you can read you primary phone number using the `TelephoneManager` system service you may need to add access phone state permission also as this is a sensitive data

```
//Java
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

in AndroidManifest.xml, give the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

You will be required to ask the "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission from the user before fetching the phone number.

Comment: tMgr.getLine1Number(); Gives null this method is not working